# GeoServer: Data Partially Disappear When Zoomed In

Tags: geoserver, postgresql

I have spatial data in PostgreSQL DB with no specified projection. Projection is forced on GeoServer side to epsg:4326.

Zone of the interest in New Zealand and islands around. The problem is with Chatham Island. Data in that area is visible at the scale of 140 M, and disappear when zoom in. While data in New Zealand area remains visible. Data goes from SQL View.

This happens even with default GeoServer style, when no min/max zoom level settings set in the style. I don't understand what's going on.

Scale 140 M - there are few points in the Island area:

[image]

But they disappear then I zoom in:

[image]

They definitely exist there, because I have managed to click to one of them, even though it is not visible. So I got attribute table under the map window.

--

Date line is relatively close, about 200 km.

[image]

The Chathams are on the other side of the 180th meridian (the basis for the international date line, which has been shifted to allow them to remain on the same day as New Zealand).

[image]

Comment: and do please set a projection on your data in the database

Comment: I have the opposite problem, I guess. Features don't draw the zoomed in. And I tried to deactivate "Support on the fly geometry simplification" and it didn't help.

Comment: please add some screen shots to show what is happening

Comment: how close to the anti-meridian is that group?

Comment: About 200km. Added screenshot in the end of the question.

Comment: Is it possible they are off the right of the screen? Otherwise it looks like a bug, can you provide a small dataset that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: I have created small test dataset and tested it on another GeoServer prior sharing. I can't reproduce this anymore. Everything is OK with the demo data. Don't know what's the miracle. Maybe a bug.

Comment: How anti-meridian proximity may affect even if this is not this case?

Comment: there is always tricky maths involved when the anti-meridian is nearby